# c++ Store reference of a maps tuple for use in another function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, tuples

in some still existing code theres a map of this type:

```
std::map<int, std::tuple<int, std::vector<HlEdgeEntry*>*>> edgesMap;
```

I now want to store the part of

```
std::tuple<int, std::vector<HlEdgeEntry*>*>
```

Within another priorityqueue.
This way, when extracting from priority queue I do not need to run .find method of the map.

This way my priorityQueue is defined as follows:

```
typedef std::pair<int, std::tuple<int, std::vector<HlEdgeEntry*>*>>
 EdgePairType;
typedef std::pair<int, EdgePairType> QueuePairType;

struct CompareQueueEntry :
 public std::binary_function<QueuePairType, QueuePairType, bool>
{
    bool operator()
     (const QueuePairType firstQueuePair,
      const QueuePairType secondQueuePair) const
    {
        return firstQueuePair.first < secondQueuePair.first;
    }
};

typedef std::priority_queue<QueuePairType, vector<QueuePairType>,
 CompareQueueEntry> PriorityQueueType;
```

The map itself is used furthermore all over the code.

Inserting into priority queue takes places in another (initQueue()) function than where to pick the next priority (doWork()).
Both methods take the priorityQueue and the map by reference such that both are defined in a third function controlWork() calling both previous mentioned methods. This looks like as follows:

```
std::map<int, std::tuple<int, std::vector<HlEdgeEntry*>*>> edgesMap;
PriorityQueueType priorityQueue;


k->initQueue(edgesOrelSource, edgesMap);
k->doWork(edgesMap, priorityQueue);
```

The problem is that after receiving the tuple from queue (within doWork()) I want to change one of the tuples values such that it affects the entry withing the map.
To be more precise I want to store the queues key into the maps tuple.first (int). I cannot do this earlier for some functional reasons.
This then looks like as follows:

```
QueuePairType currPriorityPair = priorityQueue.top();
priorityQueue.pop();

int currPriority = currPriorityPair.first;
EdgePairType currEdgePair = currPriorityPair.second;

... = currEdgePair.first;
std::tuple<int, std::vector<HlEdgeEntry*>*> currTuple =
         currEdgePair.second;

int newKey = recalculateKeyFromQueueForCurrentElement();
if(newKey > currPriority)
{
    //reinsert currElement into Queue and go to next iteration
    continue;
}

//set currPriority, cannot change any more in future
std::get<int>(currTuple) = newKey;
```

So the very last line of this code snipped shows what I want to do, such that the value inside the map has changed.

As far as I know that is not possible until I use pointers as mapped value within the map. But as I said its still existing code I would really avoid alle the changes.
But my knowledge is not best so may there are some possibilities very well.

If not, maybe theres a way of less effort?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just have a priority queue of pointers?

Comment: Your code is a bit unclear. (What is `k`? What is `edgesOrelSource`?) Can we maybe skip the details, and can you just say whether the priority queue always contains elements that are already in the map?

Comment: their other objects which do not be of interest here I think

"whether the priority queue always contains elements that are already in the map"  -> yes

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very general approach to have a central `std::map<K, T, Cmp>` and an auxiliary priority queue that manages some of the elements of the map. We implement this by storing *pointers* to map elements in the queue, but using (a copy of) the map's key comparator for the queue ordering.

We can define the queue like this:

```
using M = std::map<K, T, Cmp>;

using Q = std::priority_queue<
              M::mapped_type*, std::vector<M::mapped_type*>, QCmp<M>>;
```

Here we used:

```
template <typename M>
class QCmp
{
    using El = M::mapped_type*;
    M::key_compare cmp_;

public:
    QCmp(M::key_compare cmp) : cmp_(cmp) {}

    bool operator()(El lhs, El rhs) const
    {
        return cmp_(lhs->first, rhs->first);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
M m = /* ... */;
Q q(m.key_comp());

q.push(&m[key]);  // etc.
```

Comment: that means by just adding a & to the maps pair.second I do get a pointer to it which I can store within the queue.

in my specific case I then do while iterating over edgesMap with edgesMapIter:
    priorityQueue.push(&((*edgesMapIter).second));

That for I chance piorityQueues type to:
    typedef std::pair<int, std::tuple<int, std::vector<HlEdgeEntry*>*>*>
 EdgePairType;
--> note the added * before the last >

In your sample I wonder what
    lhs->first
does, since
    using  El = M::mapped_type*;
Which I do understand that mapped_type not necessarily does have a .second